# How to deploy katalon studio project

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder, katalon

I wonder how to deploy/build a project made with Katalon Studio (.bat/.exe/.dmg for example) for the users who don't have installed Katalon Studio on their system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not currently possible. The other side should have Katalon Studio installed and activated.

Additional info: [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/getting-started.html#activate-katalon-studio) and [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/console-mode-execution.html#execute-katalon-studio-in-console-mode).